# Get Image captcha result after form submit from a site with login

Tags: javascript, php, asp.net

I am a complete newbie to Web development. 
There is a website with link such as `https://example/login.asp` with three fields of id, password and an Image Captcha. I am creating an API where the image captcha is automatically detected or taken from the session cookie after the submit button so the user doesn't need to type it.

```
<?php

    echo '<a href = "https://example/login.asp"></a>';
    if(isset($POST['submit'])){
       echo '<pre>';
       echo print_r($_SESSION['imgCaptcha']);
       echo '</pre>';
    }
    ?>
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function (response) {
        console.log(response.getAttribute("imgCaptcha"));
    })
</script>
```

I am getting a completely blank page. What should I do and where am I going wrong.

Comment: I removed the `asp.net` tag since this seems to be php only.

Comment: @VDWWD The asp.net tag was added for the login.asp in the url

Comment: Ah, did not see that one. But why are you mixing php and asp?

Comment: @VDWWD The website that I am working with a url with .asp as the endpoint